# Pygame blit 'dest' argument was not found

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to blit text onto my surface using this line:

```
surface.blit(myFont.render(text, 1, text_color),(200,200))
```

But I get an error: TypeError: Required argument 'dest' (pos 2) not found

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening...

Comment: Is this the code you are actually using? if `surface` is actually a `Surface`, there's nothing wrong with the code. Maybe you just mixed up some `(` and `)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not giving a proper rect as the second argument to the surface.blit() function.  It needs to be a rect.  I suggest the following:

```
text=myFont.render(text, 1, text_color)
rect=text.get_rect()
rect.topleft=(200, 200)
surface.blit(text, rect)
```

To do it all in one line of code, it might get a bit complicated:

```
surface.blit(myFont.render(text, 1, text_color), pygame.Rect(200, 200, myFont.render(text, 1, text_color).get_rect().width, myFont.render(text, 1, text_color).get_rect().height)
```

If you want it to be at 200, 200 in the center, the easy, multiple-lined code would look like this:

```
text=myFont.render(text, 1, text_color)
rect=text.get_rect()
rect.centerx=200
rect.centery=200
surface.blit(text, rect)
```

In order to do it in one line, it will get rediculously long:

```
surface.blit(myFont.render(text, 1, text_color), pygame.Rect(200-myFont.render(text, 1, text_color).get_rect().width/2, 200-myFont.render(text, 1, text_color).get_rect().height/2, myFont.render(text, 1, text_color).get_rect().width, myFont.render(text, 1, text_color).get_rect().height)
```

As you can see, it would be much easier to do it in the five lines of code rather than the one line like you were trying to do, and it would probably be faster too.  Basically what you are having to do for one line is both render the text and get its rect for each parameter of the rect in order to avoid an error.  This would take a really long time, especially if you were putting this into a loop.  If you are doing it doing the loading, it might be alright, but I would still reccommend the multiple lines.

Comment: You can use `rect.center = (200, 200)`

Answer (score 0):

I found the error...

I tried to set the size of myFont to a float type. It did not seem to like that! :)

Answer (score -1):

`Surface.blit(source, dest, area=None, special_flags = 0): return Rect`

You're not setting as parameter which surface you want to draw on.
Read the documentation about [Surface.blit](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#Surface.blit) for more information

Comment: No, this is not correct. First of all, the questioneer uses `surface`, which seems to be a variable, and not `Surface`, which is the class in the actual pygame module. If he were using the class method `blit` of the `Surface` class as you wrote, he would have had an error complaining that `(200, 200)` is not a `Surface`.